# Multiple user accessing Webservice simultaneously

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

We have a `WebMethod` created in an ASP.NET 2.0 Web Service (VB), which is accessed throughout the application very frequently. The `WebMethod` gets the query as a parameter and returns the `DataSet`. It works fine when the number of users is 1 or 2. If ~30 users are using  the system simultaneously, **the `WebMethod` returns the `DataSet` of a different query**. We have tried the `synclock` (`lock` in C#) option, but it does not work.

```
Public Function ExecuteQry(ByVal StrText As String) As DataSet

        Dim AdoDs As New DataSet()
        Dim SqlDp As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim SqlCmd As New SqlCommand
        Dim SqlParam As New SqlParameter

        Try
            SyncLock AdoDs
                MakeConnect()
                With SqlCmd
                    .Connection = SqlCon
                    .CommandText = "rExecuteQry"
                    .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                End With
                SqlParam = SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@strText", Trim(StrText))
                SqlDp.SelectCommand = SqlCmd
                SqlDp.Fill(AdoDs)
                DisposeConnect()
                Return AdoDs
            End SyncLock
        Catch ex As SqlException
            DisposeConnect()
            Debug.Write(ex.Message)
        Finally

            SqlCmd = Nothing
            SqlParam = Nothing
        End Try
    End Function
```

Below is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[rExecuteQry] 
@strText   Varchar (max)
as
Exec( @StrText)
```

Comment: Source added to Question...

Comment: Please post Stored Proc aswell

Comment: From the Stored Proc, Exec(@StrText) is running the query requested. This is passed in and Trimmed from ExecuteQry(ByVal StrText As String). I can only guess that you have processes calling ExecuteQry passing in different StrText which is causing your different queries! Its that or your Trim function is causing this and you have badly named queries with spaces before\after (but this is unlikely). I would personally put logging into your method to see what is calling ExecuteQry with a different Stored Procedure string. I think this is a very dangerous pattern...

Comment: We are in Software maintanence, this is written some 6 years back. How can we overcome this...

Comment: You need to find which different procedures are being called i.e. different instances of "StrText". Once you know which ones, you will be able to debug back through the code to find out what is calling them and why.